# how to set the logelevel in Sparkjob

Tags: pyspark

How do i suppress the `logLevel` to just errors in Pyspark submit command.
I tried below inside the `.py` script but it still generates all warning logs. Im using `Python 2.6.6` on `Spark v2.2.0`   Please advise

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re,sys

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

Comment: AFAIK, you're doing the right thing

Comment: Its clear now. When i set the LogLevel('ALL') i noticed the difference,  Thanks